# Incorrect results when printing out a submatrix of a 2D array in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I'm new to C and learning about arrays. I've made a function, `print2d`, to print out a two dimensional array. I've created a 9x9 array, `array2d`. First, I printed out `array2d` using `print2d`, which worked perfectly. Then, I tried to print out a 3x3 submatrix of `array2d` that consists of elements in the first three rows and first three columns. The 3x3 submatrix is printed out incorrectly.

In main:

```
int array2d[9][9] = {
        {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
    };
    print2d(rows,cols,array2d);

    print2d(3,3,array2d); // print 3x3 submatrix
```

```
void print2d(int rows, int cols, int array[][cols])
{
    printf("{");

    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        printf("{%i",array[r][0]);
        for (int c = 1; c < cols; c++)
        {
            printf(", %i",array[r][c]);
        }
        printf("}\n");
    }
    printf("}\n");
}
```

Output:
The 9x9 matrix `array2d` is printed out properly, but the 3x3 submatrix is printed out as:

```
{{0, 1, 0}
{0, 0, 0}
{0, 0, 0}
}
```

instead of

```
{{0, 1, 0}
{0, 0, 0}
{1, 1, 0}
}
```

The first row of the submatrix is correct, but the third row is not. My guess is that by calling `print2d(3,3,array2d)`, the function `print2d` is expecting a 2d array with 3 columns (`int array[][3]`), rather than a 9x9 array. I'm not sure what kind of problem that is causing, and why the first row of the output is correct but not the third. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are passing a 2D array to a function,  but `print2d(3,3,array2d)` is lying to it about the number of columns in the array. There are `9` not `3`. Please make the distinction beween the available number of columns, and the number used. The C compiler has to know the actual number of columns, to be able to index the array properly.

Comment: .... So the function might need *four* more parameters: the sub-matrix dimensions, and its corner location.

Comment: If I pass the C compiler the wrong number of columns, what happens? Is there some kind of segfault?

Comment: @monkey king the 2d array will store as 1d array in memory, all elements of first row then second row, and so on. So if you lie about the size of array, the index that you want to get is not exact

Comment: If array 3x2: {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}} in memory the elements are stored like: 1 2 3 4 5 6. So if you say to compiler that this is an array 2x2, so the order of some values are changed.  As your result, first row is exact because the order of first row that you print is not changed. But the second and third row are difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use double pointer instead of 2D array

```
void print2d(int rows, int cols, int **array);
```

Or define the sub array as @Weather_Vane comment above:

```
void print2d(int rows, int cols, int array[rows][cols], int sub_row, int sub_col) {
   for (int r = 0; r < sub_row; r++)
    {
       ...
        for (int c = 1; c < sub_col; c++)
        {
          ...
        }
        ...
    }
    printf("}\n");
}
```

main function for array with sub array arguments

```
print2d(9,9,array2d, 9, 9);
print2d(9,9,array2d, 3, 3);
```

main function for double pointer:

```
int main() {
  int rows, cols, i;
  int **array2d;

  /* obtain values for rows & cols*/

  // allocate the array
  array2d = malloc(rows * sizeof(int));
  if (!array2d)
    return -1;
  for (i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    array2d[i] = malloc(cols * sizeof *array2d[i]);
    if(!array2d[i])
        return -1;
  }

  /*init the values of array here */

  print2d(rows,cols,array2d);
  for (i=0; i<rows; i++)
    free(array2d[rows];
  free(array2d);
}
```